# Titanium webview.reload() not working correct

Tags: android, titanium, android-webview

When I try to reload the titanium webview true  webview.reload(), the view does not reload correctly. Instead if loading the page it gives me a page not found.

what i'm doing:
In Titanium i make use of webviews to display data. These webviews make use of HTML that is stored in the local filesystem that Titanium offers. The webview is called url is set by :

```
webview.setUrl( Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory.toString() + 'index.html');
```

This sets the proper url for the webview, it let's me see the correct html page. When I use webview.reload(), it seems lost... is there a way to reload the webview, or should i remove and then add the webview again?

Comment: forgot to add that i compared the webview.url path with Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory.toString() + 'index.html'.. seems the same .

Answer (score 0):

Setting a URL for WebView the resource is usually loaded from the `Resources` folder.
So try to move all HTML files there (into `Resources`, same folder where `app.js` is located) and simply use.

```
webview.setUrl('index.html');
```

This has worked for me both on iOS and Android.

(There is an issue related to Android regarding WebView and setting its content by `html` property but this shouldn't matter here)

Comment: this actually is not possible since the resources dir is read only, i need to be able to write to the files to that's why I use the applicationDataDirectory

Comment: did you think about generating HTML on demand and set it via `html` property as content of webview?